# SFTP connection error: connection timeout

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

I'm trying to connect to SFTP server using `jsch` library. This is how I do:

```
public class SFTPConnection {

    private String sftpHost;
    private String sftpUser;
    private String sftpPass;
    private String sftpWorkDir;
    private Session session = null;
    private Channel channel = null;
    private ChannelSftp channelSftp = null;

    static final String SFTPHOST = "prod-sftp.host.ru";
    static final String SFTPUSER = "user";
    static final String SFTPPASS = "pass";
    static final String SFTPWORKINGDIRINC = "/dir/Port_Increment/";
    static final String SFTPWORKINGDIRFULL = "/dir/Port_All_Full/";

    public  SFTPConnection(String sftpHost, String sftpUser, String sftpPass, String sftpWorkDir) throws JSchException, SftpException {
        this.sftpHost = sftpHost;
        this.sftpUser = sftpUser;
        this.sftpPass = sftpPass;
        this.sftpWorkDir = sftpWorkDir;

        JSch jsch = new JSch();

        session = jsch.getSession(this.sftpUser, this.sftpHost, 3232);
        session.setPassword(this.sftpPass);
        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();
        channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect();
        channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
        channelSftp.cd(this.sftpWorkDir);
    }

    public SFTPConnection() throws JSchException, SftpException {

        sftpWorkDir = SFTPWORKINGDIRINC;
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        session = jsch.getSession(SFTPUSER, SFTPHOST, 3232);
        session.setPassword(SFTPPASS);
        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();
        channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect();
        channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
        channelSftp.cd(SFTPWORKINGDIRINC);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SFTPConnection con=new SFTPConnection();
        } catch (JSchException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SftpException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This code works on my machine, but now I need to deploy it on another server with high security level. And this is what I've got.
The exception is:

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Util.createSocket(Util.java:344)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:215)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
    at SFTPConnection.<init>(SFTPConnection.java:53)
    at SFTPConnection.main(SFTPConnection.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Util.createSocket(Util.java:338)
    ... 9 more
```

I was trying to connect using WinSCP with same parameters. I was trying to change port from `3232` to `22`, but still this error. What's wrong?

**UPD:**
I can not ping `prod-sftp.host.ru`:

```
Pinging #ipaddress# with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
```

But telnet can connect to 22-nd port.

**PS**

Most parameters are not real. Don't try to ping it yourself. I just don't wanna share host, username and password with you.

Comment: `# host -a  prod-sftp.host.ru
prod-sftp.host.ru does not exist (Authoritative answer)`

Comment: `But telnet can connect to 22-nd port.` I doubt this. What do you get ?

Comment: @PeterMmm, Of course I've changed parameters for this question. I don't wanna share my password and username too.

Comment: So `prod-sftp.host.ru` is not the host you are trying to connect ? Because all points that the server is not available on port `3232`.

Comment: No, it isn't.I think I should tell more details. Wait a min.

Comment: @PeterMmm, look at the question again, please. There is something new.

Comment: As @PeterMmm asked, what do you get when you telnet to port 22? What's a difference between 3232 and 22? Why do you connect to 3232, and not 22? What error do you get when you try to connect to 22 with WinSCP? Saying that you can connect to port A, when you really want to connect to port B is not really useful (except that proves that IP address is routable).

Comment: WinSCP works well for these parameters.

Comment: What parameters? Please try to be more specific. Do you mean port 22? If WinSCP works on port 22, why do you use port 3232 in Java?

Comment: Parameters in the code(few final fields). WinSCP works on 3232 port too.

Comment: Oh, now I remeber. 3232 is opened port on sftp server. That's why.

Comment: Can you include a log file from WinSCP for a working session?

Comment: You're saying that you deployed the app to another higher security server. Check that you can `telnet host 3232` to from the shell on _that_ server, **not your machine**. The error says it can't open a connection, chances are the server is firewalled.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to disable the firewall on either side, it is a well known fact that Java FTP is blocked by a lot of firewalls.

Have you tried to check if the host is available on the given host with another piece of software like Filezilla, just to make sure that the error is in your code and not some other place, like host name misspelling etc.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to specify timeout?
You can do it before:

session.connect();

by adding:

session.setTimeout(20000);

In my code I've also added this:

jsch.setKnownHosts(System.getProperty("user.home")+"/.ssh/known_hosts");

Regards,

Konki

Answer (score 0):

As your stacktrace told you, the client cannot establish a connection with the server. You are using ftp which does not cope too well with nowadays network infrastructure. You should probably take a look at the RFCs for FTP connections.

In short, you client connects to the control port of the server just to negotiate another port of communication.

- So first check, that your server is up using ping.
- Then try to connect to the control port using telnet.
- If it works so far check whether it is sFTP or FTPs.
- Since the real communication will be negotiated one another port check you nat/firewall. The handshake from the FTP server might not go through it.

You can always use another FTP client to check the connection first like `lftp`.

Comment: As a network/systems administrator, I would suggest skipping the first step. We typically disable ping on all of our network equipment, as a way to further prevent casual network discovery.

Comment: @NonSecwitter How do you check hosts and trace routes then?

Comment: I should say, as far as servers and workstations go, we typically don't use ICMP. I've only run into a handful of instances where I needed it, and then I could just turn it back on temporarily. It's not the worst thing to have on, but I was working in a HIGHLY secure environment, before this current job. (I might be a littler paranoid as a result)